# Добавление виджета

Tags: android, android-widgets

Пытаюсь добавить в приложение кнопку добавления виджета.. то есть , чтобы можно было прямо из приложения добавить виджет. Возможно ли такое реализовать?
Вот например при нажатии на кнопку попадаю в список виджетов `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK` . Как я могу получить ID выбранного виджета и сразу же добавить его на главный экран? Куда идти?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение! 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#Pinning

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager =
        context.getSystemService(AppWidgetManager.class);
ComponentName myProvider =
        new ComponentName(context, MyAppWidgetProvider.class);

if (appWidgetManager.isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported()) {
    // Create the PendingIntent object only if your app needs to be notified
    // that the user allowed the widget to be pinned. Note that, if the pinning
    // operation fails, your app isn't notified.
    Intent pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent = new Intent( ... );

    // Configure the intent so that your app's broadcast receiver gets
    // the callback successfully. This callback receives the ID of the
    // newly-pinned widget (EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID).
    PendingIntent successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, null, successCallback);
}
```

Comment: Все работает хорошо, только это функция доступна с API 26 (Android 8.0).

Comment: Протестировал на нескольких устройствах. Для Android 9 работает, но(!) не запускается активность настроек. Для Android 8.1 не работает, хотя функция сообщает, что данная операция доступна. Таким образом, данное решение содержит множество недочетов и ошибок, а пользователь особо не будет разбираться, что вы не виноваты и с удовольствием влепит вам единичку.

Comment: На 3х (Android 8+) устройствах проверил, прекрасно работает.  А тех ,у кого  <8 пришлось проинформировать. На форумах пишут, что это единственный вариант добавить из приложения. Буду благодарен ,если дадите способ получше ..)

Comment: xiaomi Redmi 6a Android 8.1 с кучей обновлений - не работает. Я вам верю, что у вас все прекрасно работает, только для платформы Android это не показатель. Мое дело предупредить.